# R shiny: Refresh browser while application is running

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a shiny application/server which I force to run for 20 seconds and then I run the progress bar on the browser. However, if I was to refresh the browser, then the browser does not refresh until the application has finished running. Is there a way to have the application terminate when the browser is refreshed?

This is my application. The application takes any file, then when the ActionButton is clicked, the application runs for 20 seconds. Meanwhile the progress bar will be visible at the top of the page.

In server.R

```
library(shiny)


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


  # Wait for start_proc to be clicked and then download the data frame
  get_download <- eventReactive(input$start_proc, 
                                {
                                  withProgress(message = "Processing", {
                                    n = 20
                                    for (i in 1:n){
                                      incProgress(1/n, detail = paste("", sep = ""))
                                      Sys.sleep(1)
                                    }
                                  })

                                  # Create the data frame
                                  df = data.frame(c(1,1,1),c(2,2,2))

                                  output$data_file <- downloadHandler(
                                    filename = function() {
                                      paste('probabilities-', Sys.Date(), '.txt', sep='')
                                    }
                                    ,
                                    content = function(file1) {
                                      write.table(df, file = file1)
                                    }
                                  )
                                })

  # Observe when file is uploaded
  observe({

    inFile <- input$upload

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)


    get_download()

  })

})
```

In ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fixedPage(
   fileInput("upload", ""),
   actionButton("start_proc", h5("Compute Probability\n")),
   downloadButton("data_file"),
   helpText("Download will be available once the processing is completed.")
))
```